# Do any standard copulas fit well these sampled bivariate data--exhibiting repulsive behavior--having uniform marginals

Tags: correlation, joint-distribution, computational-statistics, copula, bivariate

I'm currently developing a data set that consists of two $50 \times 50$ matrices, which I designate as q1 and Q1.

I strongly believe (bordering on formal proof [cf. Corollary 1 in [marginalinvariance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01410)]) that the ratio of Q1 to q1 constitutes a sample from a (symmetric) bivariate copula (alternatively termed "permutons or doubly-stochastic measures" [WikiCopula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory))) $f(x,y)$ with uniform marginals over [0,1]. Now  $x$ and $y$ ("Bloch radii" of quantum bit [qubit] systems--also "quadratic Casimir invariants" [CasimirInvariants](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07210)) appear "repulsive" in nature [RepulsiveBehavior](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07210), that is the 45-degree line $x=y$ has relatively low values.

Unfortunately, the rather involved quantum-information-theoretic process [RandomMatrixGeneration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3570) employed to generate the data sets yields more lower values of $x$ and $y$ $\in [0,1]$ than higher values. It is not computationally feasible to uniformly sample $x$ and $y$ over [0,1] and obtain the $4 \times 4$ density matrices that fulfill the requisite properties [RequirementsForDensityMatrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix).

So, my question is can the ratio of Q1 to q1 be well fitted by any of the standard Gaussian or Archimedean or other copulas?

The developing Q1 and q1 data sets as well as a plot of Q1/q1--are displayed in [BivariateCopulaRepulsive](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08739).  I intend to update q1 and Q1 as their entries further increase in size. So, the $\{i,j\}$ cells of q1 and  Q1 should be considered to correspond to $x=\frac{2 i-1}{100}$ and  $y=\frac{2 j-1}{100}$.

Two calculations now inserted near the end of the linked Mathematica program show the near uniformity over [0,1] of the two
marginal distributions.

Can any known forms (Gaussian, Archimedean,...) of copulas be well-fitted to these data? A Gaussian copula with uniform marginals over [0,1] would be quite appealing conceptually--due to the wide range of applicability of multivariate normal distributions.

Comment: Are you trying to tell us the sampling process is biased?  If not, then "yields more lower values" is *prima facie* evidence that the marginals are *not* uniform.  If so, then exactly in what way is it biased?  We can't help you correct that bias until we have some clear characterization of it.  Regarding your title, by *definition* there exists *some* copula that models this process, so the answer is trivially "yes."

Comment: whuber, thanks! I'm NOT sampling uniformly over x and y in [0,1]. I get the results by generating "density matrices"( in quantum parlance)--giving me the q1 results and testing whether they pass a "separability" test--in which case they are counted in the Q1 set. The z in the z-axis is the "separability probability".

Comment: Your setting is obscure.  We really need more details about what you are doing. As it stands, your question is asking for the trivial answer I gave: yes, assuming your sampling is unbiased, you can fit $Q_1/q_1$ with a copula. If by "standard" you mean some severely restricted class of copulas (which doesn't seem to be the case, since you invite "other" forms), then the answer might change--but again we suffer from a lack of detail and clarity in your statement of the problem.

Comment: Cross-posted on [Quantitative Finance SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69167).

Comment: Could you create a more concise and complete description of what you are doing. Currently it is a broad collection of separate terms and links to other pages from which it is not easy to grasp the idea. Just in order to get the plot of Q1/q1 I have to download a 9.3 mB and 20 page large article and browse through it. And, that is just one of the many links and pieces of information in your post. If you put your question in a more approachable format,  then you will reach a much larger public and number of people that might answer your question.

Comment: It would be especially nice if you use the question to explain more about the alinea: *"The developing Q1 and q1 data sets as well as a plot of Q1/q1..."*

Comment: We generated 2,548,000,000 two-qubit density matrices, randomly with respect to Hilbert-
Schmidt measure, using the simple (Ginibre ensemble) algorithm outlined in [36, eq. (1)].
(That is: “(a) prepare a square complex random matrix A of size N pertaining to the Ginibre
ensemble (with real and imaginary parts of each element being independent normal random
variables); (b) compute the matrix H = AA?/(tr AA?), (generically positive definite)” [13].)...

Comment: ...For each such matrix, we found the values of rA and rB, as well as performed the well-
known Peres-Horodecki (determinantal-based [37]) test for separability [38, 39] on the partial
transpose of ρ.

Comment: The references 36, 37, 38, 39 and 13 might be well know to the reader with experience in this topic (and that's why exact/further explanations are often skipped in formal articles), but could you elaborate more about this process in your post. I believe that this part is critical for understanding the question.

Comment: S.  E. --Thanks very much for your detailed comments!

Comment: @PaulB.Slater I have been trying to read into the statistics of these qubits. But, to me it feels a bit like a minefield of specialist bits of concepts and definitions (even while I have a basic knowledge of quantum physics). I was thinking of making a separate question that is just about trying to understand the concept of your question and bringing it down to a simpler description that is known by pure mathematicians and statisticians.

Comment: What  I am trying to understand is **1** How are the random matrices defined/created (I currently have the idea that it is $a^\dagger a/trace(a^\dagger a)$ with $a$ a 4x4 matrix with complex entries whose components are each normal distributed.  **2** How is the seperability defined (something with being able to write the matrix as a product, but I am not exactly clear about how) and compute it (something with a negative discriminant) **3** How are the $r_i$ computed (some sort of reparametrization. I've seen it explained as the Bloch radius of a single qubit but not how it works for 2 qubits)