# What are examples of symmetric copulas $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ having relative minima for $f(x,x)$?

Tags: density-function, count-data, copula, bivariate, symmetry

In a previous posting on this site [RepulsiveBehavior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557739/do-any-standard-copulas-fit-well-these-sampled-bivariate-data-exhibiting-repuls) I attempted to detail
a quantum-information-theoretic separability/entanglement problem I am pursuing. Detailed issues of sampling sizes for a data set being developing were raised and perhaps obscured the chief question I hope to have addressed/clarified.

That is, based on  my study [BlochRadiiRepulsion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08739), I believe that I am dealing with a symmetric copula $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ defined over the unit square for which the values of $f(x,x)$ assume relative minima.

Might there be any standard copulas (at least for certain parameter settings) exhibiting such behavior that I could try to fit to these data being developing? My attempts to do so [MathematicaQuestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261320/can-the-copuladistributions-be-fitted) have not so far been successful in this regard.

Here is a plot of the pdf based on my sampling procedure

[image: CopulaPDF]

The relative minima along  $x=y$ are discernible.

Here is a further plot of the residuals from this pdf of a weighted least-squares fit of the Ali-Mikhail-Haq (AMH) model with estimated parameter 0.0192858.

[image: ResidualsFromAMHfit]

Comment: By *relative minima* do you mean the density along the $y=x$ axis is the lowest within the unit square?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, RH! Subject to my sampling and obvious lack of full knowledge of the governing process (for which I am searching for possible rules), it appears that if one deviates from the x = y line, the probabilities increase.

Comment: If you consider the relationship between the copula and the conditional distributions, you will immediately deduce that the copula is non-decreasing in both arguments.  Consequently, the only relative (strict) minimum it can possibly have is at $(0,0).$

Comment: whuber--does this comment extend as well to the pdf, my principal focus of analysis? In any case, I'm interested in models, in which strong repulsion (relatively low values) is shown for x = y, if still not over the entire line.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Because you have used "$f$" as a symbol for a copula, the standard understanding is that $f(u,v)$ is the probability of the rectangle $[0,u]\times[0,v].$ Upon rereading your post I now suspect you are referring to an associated *copula density,* given (when it exists) by the second order mixed partial derivative. If so, about the only way to proceed would be to refer to a list of whatever you consider "standard" copulas to be, take those derivatives, and plot them along the diagonal. A better approach would be to construct a copula suitable for your problem.

Comment: I must admit that for some time I was thinking of copula in its PDF representation rather than the CDF. However, I'm still asking for assistance either in newly constructing a copula PDF with the requested "repulsion" property, or being directed to some "standard" one already exhibiting this property (at least possibly for some particular parameter values, if a family of copulas).

Comment: The illustration helps.  It makes one wonder: why do you even want to use a copula?  What is it intended to accomplish?  Instead of focusing on a specific *method,* you are likely to get more useful answers by articulating your *goals* (along with descriptions of the information you have to work with and your constraints, of course).  That would allow people to suggest methods that might be better than the one you are focusing on.